# @UserCannotOwnCourse cannot create a course in google classroom

Tags: node.js, google-classroom

What I have:

- Service account
- Domain delegation created (ID of service account) and google classroom permissions
- Created a admin account (admin@mydomain.edu)
- Trying to create a course impersonating with the admin account
- Google for education workspace

Question: why am I getting @UserCannotOwnCourse error?

My Code:

Service account jwt:

```js
function getAuthServiceAccount(dominio, impersonateEmail) => {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        let credentials = getCredentials();
        const jwtParams = {
            email : credentials.client_email,
            key   : credentials.private_key,
            scopes : [
                ////// drive
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
                ///// classroom
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.announcements',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.announcements.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.topics',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.topics.readonly',
                /////// admin directory
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.customer',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.customer.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.alias',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.alias.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userschema',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userschema.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly'
            ]
        };
        if(impersonateEmail) {
            jwtParams.subject = impersonateEmail;
        }
        const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(jwtParams);
        jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
            if (err) {
                return resolve(false);
            } else {
                jwtClient.dominio = dominio;
                return resolve(jwtClient);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Create course:

```js
function create_course(auth, courseName, room, ownerEmail) {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        const classroom = google.classroom('v1');
        const data = {
            auth : auth,
            resource : {
                name        : courseName,
                section     : room,
                room        : room,
                ownerId     : ownerEmail,
                courseState : 'ACTIVE'
            }
        };
        classroom.courses.create(data, async (err, response) => {
            if(err) {
                return resolve({msj : `Error!!!`, err : err});
            }
            return resolve({msj : 'course created!', id : response.data.id, code : response.data.enrollmentCode });
        });
    });
}
```

Invocation:

```js
let ownerEmail = 'owner@mydomain.edu'; // << NOT the admin email I'm impersonating with

const _AUTH = await getAuthServiceAccount('mydomain.edu', 'admin@mydomain.edu'); // << email to impersonate (subject)
let res = await create_course(_AUTH, 'Math', 'Room 123', ownerEmail);
```

I get this error:

```
{
    code: 403,
    message: '@UserCannotOwnCourse Please check that the user account exists. If you are attempting to create a course for another user, ensure that you are admin of their domain.',
    errors: [ 
{
    message: '@UserCannotOwnCourse Please check that the user account exists. If you are attempting to create a course for another user, ensure that you are admin of their domain.',
    domain: 'global',
    reason: 'forbidden'
  } 
],
    status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED'
  }
```

It's really admin:

[image]

Note: This works in another workspace with the very same configuration, matter of fact in many workspaces I manage this works, this is the first time I get this error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. I can successfully create a course with a service account that impersonates an admin account, in which the owner is not the same account as the admin account. Can you check whether the behavior changes if you (1) change the ownerId, (2) change the admin account, (3) call this directly with the admin account, not via service account.

Comment: I know I have another account where it works just as you say, but in this one it doesn't. I had to add the admin account to classroom google group and it worked, weird because as I said it works without having to add it to the group.

Comment: My guess is that user is not on the list of accounts who can create classes (either not a teacher, or not a verified teacher - see [Decide who can create classes](https://support.google.com/edu/setup/answer/6071551?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdecide-who-can-create-classes)). Do you think that could be the case?

Comment: I also checked that, I had "All pending and verified teachers" selected in both accounts I manage but they behaved differently

Comment: Have you checked whether the account who should own the course is a pending/verified teacher or not?

Comment: you mean if that teacher is in the classroom group? it is not but in other account I managed is not either and works fine.

Comment: As far as I know, if the user is [not in the teacher group name](https://support.google.com/edu/setup/answer/6071551?hl=en#zippy=%2Cverify-teachers%2Cchange-a-users-role-from-teacher-to-student) and [Teacher permissions](https://support.google.com/edu/setup/answer/6071551?hl=en#zippy=%2Cverify-teachers%2Cdecide-who-can-create-classes) is set to `All pending an verified teachers`, that user should not be able to create classes. Are you sure there's no difference between both accounts?